# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TasksCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I started receiving the error and can't figure out what's wrong. Am I missing something?

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', []);

app.controller('TasksCtrl', [
  '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = Task.query({
      status: 'incompleted'
    });

   $scope.completed_tasks = Task.query({
     status: 'completed'
    });

 }
]);
```

**html**

```
<div ng-controller='TasksCtrl' class='tasks-container'>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing obvious wrong with you code. Can you show the code of `Task` service

Comment: @Satpal no..He missed to add `Task` service instance

Comment: @PankajParkar, Agreed but In that scenario `Task` would be `undefined` not `TasksCtrl`, It is a possibility OP is redefining the module.

Comment: @Satpal yes..I think you identified the correct issue..he must be initializing  app twice

Comment: @PankajParkar Yeap. He is right. I have created two js files, but their modules are named differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `Task` service dependency as you are using it inside your controller.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('TasksCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {
    $scope.tasks = Task.query({
      status: 'incompleted'
    });

   $scope.completed_tasks = Task.query({
     status: 'completed'
    });

 }
]);
```

I'm assuming that you have defined `Task` service already somewhere, if not then you should add it in your code.

**Edit**

Though I added an answer which does solve you other problem. I think you have declared your app twice in your code while defining service. At that time the initially assigned controller gets flushed from the module and you are getting the `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TasksCtrl' is not a function` error